# How to test if an object is a lock?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading, standard-library, factory-method

How would you test if an object is a `threading.Lock` or `multiprocessing.Lock` (and their respective `RLock`s?). These objects in Python (3, at least) are factory methods, so you can't just do:

```
isinstance(obj, threading.Lock)
```

As this would give:

```
TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have an instance, you can get its type. So the simple solution is to do

```
threading_Lock = type(threading.Lock())
isinstance(obj, threading_Lock)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple way:

```
isinstance(obj, type(threading.Lock()))
```